# Is It Not Possible To Declare A Variable of Abstract Type In C++?

Tags: c++, variables, polymorphism, declaration

I have the following switch statement in C++ where `BaseType` is an abstract class:

```
switch (foo)
{
    case 1:
    {
        DerivedType t = SomeDerivedType(); //Instantiate some derived type.
        FunctionThatTakesBaseType(t);   //Pass it to this function.
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        SomeOtherDerivedType t = SomeOtherDerivedType(); //Instantiate some other dervied type.
        FunctionThatTakesBaseType(t)          //Pass it to the same function.
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If this were C#, I'd write this more succinctly by declaring a base type variable outside of the switch statement, defining it in the switch, and calling the function just once *after* the switch, like this:

```
BaseType t;  //Declared outside of scope of the switch so I can call the function once afterward.
switch (foo)
{
case 1:
    t = new SomeDerivedType();
    break;
case 2:
    t = new SomeOtherDerivedType();
    break;
case 3:
    ...
}
FunctionThatTakesBaseType(t);
```

Is there a way to do this in C++? How do you *declare* an abstract type variable in an outer scope and define it with a concrete type in an inner scope? Is there a way to write C++ code as briefly as the C# code? You can't do this:

```
Base t; //ERROR: In C++ this attempts to instantiate the abstract base class!
```

And it seems like you can't do this:

```
Base* t; //OK, but to assign the variable inside the switch do you have to allocate the 
         //object on the heap?
```

Comment: *"but to assign the variable inside the switch do you have to allocate the object on the heap?"* -- Why is this a problem? Isn't this what C# does?

Comment: An abstract data type (generally speaking, a type with pure virtual functions) cannot be instantiated.  An instance of that type cannot be created which (among other possibilities) means a variable of that type cannot be declared or defined.    Creating a pointer or reference to such a type is allowed, and such pointers or references can refer to objects of concrete types *derived* from the abstract data type (to become concrete, a class must explicitly/unambiguously override *all* inherited pure virtual functions it inherits from all its bases).

Comment: And, no, it is not necessary to create objects (of derived types) "on the heap".   The key is ensuring that a reference/pointer to an object refers to a valid object (i.e. the lifetime of the object does not end before the reference/pointer is used to access the object).   A common way of doing that is dynamic allocation (erroneously described as creating it "on the heap") but there are other ways.

Comment: If you really cannot use heap allocated, then use `std::variant<std::monostate, SomeDerivedType, SomeOtherDerivedType> t;`.  (C# uses heap allocated; in C# `BaseType t;` is a *pointer* (in C++ terminology).)

Comment: @JaMiT I wanted to avoid heap allocation because it's slower than stack allocation. In the first (C++) version the object is stack-allocated, which is of course significantly faster than dynamically allocating memory from the heap. In C# (I am a professional C# developer) the object is heap-allocated as Eljay stated above)--the C# version is really like the C++ pointer version with heap allocation, but C#'s syntax hides that fact.

Comment: @ToddBurch So when you wrote *"Is there a way to do this [the C# version] in C++?"* you really meant *"Is there a way to get the C# version **plus stack allocation** in C++ without paying a price in syntax?"* In principle, such a goal is not impossible, but it does seem questionable to throw in the extra requirement as if it was nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes*, you do have to use a pointer and heap allocation.

```
BaseType *t; 

switch (foo)
{
case 1:
    t = new SomeDerivedType();
    break;
case 2:
    t = new SomeOtherDerivedType();
    break;
case 3:
    ...
}
```

You might also consider using a smart pointer. E.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<BaseType> t; 

switch (foo)
{
case 1:
    t = std::make_unique<SomeDerivedType>();
    break;
case 2:
    t = std::make_unique<SomeOtherDerivedType>();
    break;
case 3:
    ...
}
```

This is exactly what's happening in languages where all objects are allocated on the heap.

Stack allocation relies on knowing the size of an object. A virtual base class doesn't indicate the size of the derived class. Consider:

```
struct X {
    virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};

struct Y : public X {
    std::string mem_var;

    Y(std::string m) : mem_var(m) { }

    std::string to_string() override {
        return mem_var;
    }
};

struct Z : public X {
    std::string to_string() override {
        return "Z";
    }
}
```

Do instances of `Y` and `Z` require the same amount of memory?

Comment: Thanks--understood. But isn't the original C++ version (first appearing in the question) allocating the objects on the stack? So perhaps a bit more verbose, but more efficient than the heap-allocated (pointer) version?

Comment: Edited to address that.

Comment: Great, thanks. So to summarize: The first (C++) example in my question works because it is instantiating the concrete type in the individual case statement. The C# version works because it's essentially using a pointer and heap allocation under the hood. Declaring the variable outside of the switch scope is impossible since allocating space for it in that stack frame would require the compiler to know the size of the object which can't be known until the concrete type is known. Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: Glad it helped! Keep in mind that _pointer_ sizes are known at compile time.

Comment: Which explains why the pointer version is possible and the stack allocation version (where the variable is declared outside the scope of the switch) is impossible.